# CakePhp 1.3 and 2.0 API for offline use

Tags: cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

Is there any link to download cakePHP 1.3 and 2.0 API for offline reading? I searched the web a lot but everybody is talking about to generate API by https://github.com/cakephp/api_generator

Is there no solution for persons like me who are not able to or don't want to use such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a copy of the http://api.cakephp.org website locally for offline use by cloning the git repository for the site and following the instructions in the README found here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp-api-docs/tree/2.x

Answer (score -1):

download the epub format from http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/
you will need tool like calibre (http://calibre-ebook.com/download_windows) to read the document though

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am looking for API(http://api.cakephp.org/) not for Documentation (http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/)